# Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' ,objc_setAssociatedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I am using an associated reference as storage for a property of my category

header file  contains :

```
@interface UIImageView (Spinning)

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL animating;

@end
```

implementation is

```
- (void)setAnimating:(BOOL)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, animatingKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

However, I am getting the warning for the line above

```
Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

if you know what I am doing wrong here, please help how to avoid this problematic

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `objc_setAssociatedObject` function expects an Objective-C object for the 3rd parameter. But you are trying to pass in a non-object `BOOL` value.

This is no different than trying to add a `BOOL` to an `NSArray`. You need to wrap the `BOOL`.

Try:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, animatingKey, [NSNumber numberWithBool:value], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Of course you will need to extract the `BOOL` value from the `NSNumber` when you get the associated object later.

Update: Using modern Objective-C you can do:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, animatingKey, @(value), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)
```

objc_setAssociatedObject accepts id type of value as third parameter and you are trying to pass BOOL to it. So make conversion as needed.