# Objective-C - Effective Subclassing of Cocoa Class Clusters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, subclass

I have an object that used to be an NSMutableSet but needed some more stuff attached to it.  The obvious (and obviously not supported) thing to do is to subclass NSMutableSet and tack on the two additional properties.  Since NSMutableSet, like basically all Cocoa data structures, is a class cluster I cannot subclass it in the usual way, since the super class just throws exceptions.  This led me down several paths.

The first path was to create sort of a composite object that declared itself as a subclass of NSMutableSet but really just forwarded the invocations to an internal NSMutableSet.  I didn't want to have to implement every method on NSMutableSet, so I thought `forwardInvocation:` would be a good way to accomplish my mission.  Unfortunately, the abstract class of NSMutableSet implements all of the methods on the interface and their implementations throw exceptions, so I was never getting to the point where I could forward an invocation.

The second path was to subclass NSProxy and forward the invocation from there.  This solution falls short in that I need to copy the interface of NSMutableSet over unless there's a way to declare "this class implements this interface" that I don't know about (this could very well be the solution).

The third path was to create a category on NSMutableSet and import it just for the class that needs to use it but that falls short since you cannot add non-dynamic properties via a category.  That led me to using associated objects in a category.  I'm willing to admit that that is the correct solution for this use case, but I wish it weren't since it's kind of clunky.  It's doubly clunky since the properties I'm adding are primitive so I'll have to wrap and unwrap them when setting and getting the association (unless there's a way to associate primitives which I'm unfamiliar with).

Essentially, what I would like is something that behaves functionally as a subclass of NSMutableSet (and all class clusters) but cannot figure out the best approach.  Thanks!

Comment: I want to be clear because of what everyone is saying. I know I'm not supposed to subclass a class cluster.  If I were supposed to it would be as easy as subclassing it and going on with my life. I am in a position where some new required fields are the cleanest solution and I don't want to rewrite all of the code that uses this set to use a new object.  It still wants fast enumeration and other set goodies and I, like a good dev, want to be as lazy as possible on the implementation of this.

Associated objects it is.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You haven't really said? Subclassing class clusters is tricky but not impossible. You left out the most obvious and easy thing which is composition. You make the set a property or ivar of your own class, implement the wrapper methods for the set methods you use, add and properties and handling in between. Composition is one of the best routes in Objective-C

Comment: @uchuugaka Did you read my question? "The first path was to create sort of a composite object..." is in the first sentence of the second paragraph.  I also explain why that's a pain.  Implementing the wrapper methods is a hassle that I didn't want to go through, especially because as soon as there's a new method added or whatever my composition stops working properly.  Obviously for this specific purpose NSMutableSet is unlikely to change much, but the question is, in general, how can I go about subclassing a class cluster without implementing wrapper methods.

Comment: Declaring as a subclass is not the same as strict composition. Composition would not subclass NSMutableSet but make an instance of NSMutableSet a member property or ivar of the composition class. The composition class does not need to do anything more than provide an interface that implements the methods you need. You can respond to the method isKindOfClass: however you like. What everyone is telling you is implementing a class cluster subclass is more hassle than composition and wrapping methods. Mainly you never know what private concrete class instances are returned by Apple class clusters.

Comment: and yes I read it. but what you describe is subclassing, not composition in the strict design pattern sense.

Comment: Composition is not an option.  It does not matter why it's not, but take it off the table.  I know what composition is and I am not going to write an interface identical to NSMutableSet, or even just the methods on NSMutableSet I'm calling. Call it stubbornness or laziness or whatever, but I want to just attach two primitives to an NSMutableSet without breaking code that assumes the object is an NSMutableSet.  Think of it as more of an academic exercise if you must.

Comment: Fair. Go with CRD's suggestion. Just test hard. If refactoring is out, and it certainly could be if other areas are still using the standard class, I can fathom why it would be more headaches not to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, let's look at your first path:

> create sort of a composite object that declared itself as a subclass of `NSMutableSet` but really just forwarded the invocations to an internal `NSMutableSet`

Can you subclass an `NSMutableSet`? Yes, but should you? The documentation for `NSMutableSet` says:

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> There should be little need of subclassing. If you need to customize behavior, it is often better to consider composition instead of subclassing.

So weigh that up and if you want to subclass refer again to the documentation:

> *Methods to Override*
>
> In a subclass, you must override both of its primitive methods:
>
> `addObject:`
>
> `removeObject:`
>
> You must also override the primitive methods of the `NSSet` class.

And looking at the `NSSet` class documentation we find its primitive methods are:

> *Methods to Override*
>
> In a subclass, you must override all of its primitive methods:
>
> `count`
>
> `member:`
>
> `objectEnumerator`

That's it, 5 methods.

You can define your own class as a subclass of `NSMutableSet`, add an instance variable which is an instance of `NSMutableSet`, implement 5 methods and redirect them to the set instance, add whatever init methods you wish, and then add your additional properties.

If performance is of concern then the tradeoff is between redirecting those five methods and accessing associated objects for your additional properties. You'll need to profile to work that out, but if and only if performance becomes an issue.

Comment: Oh, so I wouldn't have to override the set operations like union and the like?

Comment: @DrGodCarl - Exactly, the documentation makes it clear you only have to override the primitive methods; the other methods are implemented in terms of the primitive ones. You also override any init methods you wish to support or implement your own init methods; in these you do the normal `super` init and setting up of your instance variables - which is where you create the underlying set.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to subclass Cocoa class clusters will just create an awful lot of hurt. It may seem a good idea, but you will forever run into problems.

Just create an NSObject with an NSMutableSet as the first member object.

Comment: I would do this if it were a viable and quick solution, but there's already code that uses NSMutableSet and would have to rewritten to use this new thing.  A subclass would alleviate that by already having all of the methods used.

Comment: It's composition. It's easy enough to wrap methods you call and insert your owning class everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing Cocoa class cluster is kind of discouraged. Not without reasons. Please do not enter this crashy world.

Either of your solutions will work. I've successfully used the first path with `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, so I believe it should work fine for `NSMutableSet` as well. Just remember that you need to override not only `forwardInvocation:`, but a few of other methods as well. Please consult *Surrogate Objects* sections of Apple docs:

> Although forwarding mimics inheritance, the NSObject class never confuses the two. Methods like respondsToSelector: and isKindOfClass: look only at the inheritance hierarchy, never at the forwarding chain.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

In my case, I've overridden:

- `conformsToProtocol:`
- `isKindOfClass:`
- `isMemberOfClass:`
- `respondsToSelector:`
- `instancesRespondToSelector:`
- `forwardInvocation:`
- `methodSignatureForSelector:`
- `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:`

from which `isKindOfClass:`, `conformsToProtocol:` and `respondsToSelector:` are definitely crucial.

I've also used the third path with good results, but I admit the associated objects API is clunky.

Comment: I've read the documentation there a few times. I'll give it a try with the additional methods.  It seems like overkill for this, which is why I'll be using associated objects, but it could be a good tool to have in my belt if it is indeed a successful approach.

Answer (score 2):

First, gnasher729 is correct. Don't subclass class clusters. Just don't do it. Can you do it? If I tell you that you can't, will it help you convince yourself that you shouldn't? I can lie if it helps you make good choices.

But in all seriousness, it is almost always meaningless as well. Is your subclass really a specific *kind* of set? Or is it really kind of *like* a set. Consider `NSAttributedString`. It isn't a kind of string, it has-a string. This is almost always better.

And also, class clusters happen to be a royal pain to subclass.

That said, adding associated values onto a data structure, as you've already discovered, is generally just fine, because what you really want is "hey, I have some data that needs to go along with this other data." Wrapping has gotten so easy that it shouldn't really slow you down. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14918158/97337:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, animatingKey, @(value), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

And with ["one weird trick"](https://twitter.com/bbum/status/3609098005), you can make this really easy:

```
@interface NSObject (BoolVal)
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL boolVal;
@end

@implementation NSObject (BoolVal)

- (BOOL)boolVal {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, _cmd) boolValue];
}

- (void)setBoolVal:(BOOL)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(boolVal), @(value), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

But I'd still come back to the question of whether this is *really* a kind of set (rather than just *like* a set), and whether it really needs to respond to *every* message that can be sent to a set. As with `NSAttributedString`, your real needs are often much smaller than that in practice, and wrapping the handful of methods you need is often worth the simplicity and control.